# Проблема с console.log в прототипе конструктора

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста причину, по которой после `f.call(console, x)` итерация не прерывается (а должна вообще после `f.call()` прерывается) и выполняется следующий код.

```
function rangeTwo(from, to)
{
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}

rangeTwo.prototype = {

    foreach: function(f) {
        for (var x = Math.ceil(this.from); x <= this.to; x++) {
            if (f == console.log) {
                f.call(console, x);
                continue;
            }
            f(x); // Без continue выполняется
        }
    }

};
```

Костыль подставил в виде `continue`. Если убрать его, то отваливается с ошибкой, понимаю почему...для `log` значение `this` должно указывать на `console`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а что собственно не правильно: [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xiwuvi/2/edit?js,console,output) - не должна она прерываться. `f.call` - это просто способ вызвать функцию с нужным контекстом, он не прерывает выполнение цикла или прочего асинхронного кода.

Comment: Спасибо, мои ожидания были не совсем правильными.